# How to turn off Xcode 5 warnings about upgrading project?

Tags: ios, xcode

My question is partially related to this one [After update to Xcode 5 - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 or armv7s linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311075/after-update-to-xcode-5-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-armv7-or-armv)

The problem is: I have several projects which project files are automatically generated. After upgrade to 5th version, Xcode started to show me warnings regarding "Build only active architectures" so after some googling I discovered the problem which described in a question I've mentioned. So basically there is a good reason not to enable that behaviour and I end up with a lot of warnings which are kind of annoying. Of course I do not want to suppress all warnings just these ones.

Does someone know how to turn off Xcode 5 warnings about upgrading project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Build settings -> Architectures You need to add armv7 only. Remove armv7s.
[image]

Comment: But I still need to build for armv7s.

Comment: which compiler used in your build options?  LLVM 0r GCC?

Comment: default LLVM only. While previous versions project is updated to xCode5 means, it will not update to LLVM. we need to change manually.