# Phonegap App doesn't run on iOS7

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios7

I'm really having troubles to build&run my App on the iPhone 5S.
I use Cordova 2.5.0 and XCode 5.0

I'm getting these 10 Errors when trying to build&run on the iPhone 
http://www.looks-familiar.com/stacko.html

also i added a screen of my Architecture Setting - maybe the problem is somwhere there 
http://www.looks-familiar.com/stacko2.html

I changed the armv7 to "standard architectures (including 64bit)(armv7,armv7s,armv64)
Was this right, or do I have to change the settings somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use those settings: [Printscreen](http://caiovaccaro.com.br/cordovalibsettings.jpg)

I hope this helps.

I'm not sure how phonegap 2.5 will behave so if you still have problems maybe you should try to upgrade to at least 2.9.

If you don't have these settings is because this is a bug from a old version of Phonegap with a new version o XCode (4.5 upwards) as this issue states: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1360

On the comments of the issue you see that you have to manually edit the file in order to add these settings.

Because the issue is a bit old you also should include: "ARCHS[sdk=iphoneos7.*]" = "armv7 armv7s";

I had problems with armv7s and old version of Phonegap so my look like this:

```
ARCHS = armv7;  
"ARCHS[sdk=iphoneos*]" = armv7;  
"ARCHS[sdk=iphoneos6.*]" = armv7;  
"ARCHS[sdk=iphoneos7.*]" = armv7;  
"ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = i386;
```

Comment: ok thank you, seems that i have to upgrade, because i don't have that setting, you've posted

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue (but with the latest Cordova 3.1), and the cause of the issue for me turned out to be the "Build Active Architecture Only" setting, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17327694/1801118

Although in my case, I found that it also works fine when set to "Yes" for Debug, as long as the settings in both the main project and the CordovaLib sub-project matched (one was Yes and one was No originally, which caused the problem).

My Architectures setting (on both projects) is set to Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s) - I haven't been able to try the 64bit setting as I'm still targetting iOS 5.