# Apple Mach-O linker errors using Cordova 2.4, Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, linker

I updated the system to 10.8 from 10.5, updated Xcode. Then I imported the project, which was followed by Xcode changing settings of the project. Then trying to build the iPhone App failed  due to incorrect Build Phases settings. I had to re-add bunch of frameworks.

Then it compiled but I got more than 200 Apple Mach-O linker errors. Very similar issue like here: [After update to Xcode 5 - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 or armv7s linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311075/after-update-to-xcode-5-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-armv7-or-armv)
Only difference is that after following all the advices I still wasn't able to build the app.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> "_ABAddressBookAddRecord", referenced from:
>
> > ```
> >  ___20-[CDVContacts save:]_block_invoke_2 in libCordova.a(CDVContacts.o)
> > ```
>
> "_ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople", referenced from:
>
> > ```
> >  ___22-[CDVContacts search:]_block_invoke_2 in libCordova.a(CDVContacts.o)
> > ```
>
> "_ABAddressBookCreate", referenced from:
>
> > ```
> >  -[CDVContacts peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:] in libCordova.a(CDVContacts.o)
> >  -[CDVAddressBookHelper createAddressBook:] in libCordova.a(CDVContacts.o)
> > ```
>
> "_ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions", referenced from:
>
> > ```
> >  -[CDVContacts peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:] in libCordova.a(CDVContacts.o)
> >  -[CDVAddressBookHelper createAddressBook:] in libCordova.a(CDVContacts.o)
> > -[CDVContacts peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:] in libCordova.a(CDVContacts.o)
> >  -[CDVAddressBookHelper createAddressBook:] in libCordova.a(CDVContacts.o)
> > ```
>
> "_ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID", referenced from:
>
> > ```
> >  ___30-[CDVContacts displayContact:]_block_invoke in libCordova.a(CDVContacts.o)
> >  -[CDVContacts peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:] in libCordova.a(CDVContacts.o)
> > ```

Any help appreciated

Comment: It appeared as if libCordova is not compiled for i386 architecture.

Comment: libCordova should recompile each time you build and should be fine with i386. Did you re-add the frameworks only to your project or to the CordovaLib project as well? My 2.2 CordovaLib needs AddressBook, CoreMedia, AudioToolbox, AVFoundation, CoreLocation, MobileCoreServices, SystemConfiguration, AddressBookUI, UIKit, Foundation and CoreGraphics. These should be added in the Frameworks folder inside CordovaLib.xcodeproj.

Answer (score 2):

Your Xcode project doesn't link against the **AddressBook.framework**.

Go to the Build Phases and add the missing framework in the *"Link Binary With Libraries"* section.