# Testflight error: This build doesn't support iPhone 5c GSM. Ask the developers to support your device

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, testflight

Im new to iphone development. I have created new phonegap app and installed couple of plugins. Im using testflight.com to install and test apps on devices. 
Last time i have installed facebook connect plugin and made required settings. App working fine on xcode simulators and created new archive. There is no error while uploading on testflight.com.

but when i tried to install on my registered device, i got this error in safari.

Testflight error: This build doesn't support iPhone 5c GSM. Ask the developers to support your device

I googled this message but couldn't get any appropriate answer.

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Do you see this device added in the dashboard?

Comment: I just upgraded to Xcode 5.1 and am now seeing this issue without changing any settings.  Anyone see a solution?

Answer (score 24):

Have had the same issue a few times, saying not compatible iPhone 4, 4S etc, though this was fixed when I simply archived the app with 'iOS Device' selected rather than archiving for a device that's plugged in at the time. Archiving for a device that's plugged in seemed to pick up its architecture build, which if it is a newer device that is being run on may cause this 'incompatible' issue with older devices.

By archiving with simply 'iOS device' option selected this solved the issue. (contrary to what I initially thought, archiving doesn't need to be with an actual device connected, just as long as it's not the simulator.)

[image]

Hope this helps,

cheers Jim.

Comment: This was the solution to the problem when I faced it - it makes sense really, it's just one of those annoying Apple things...

Comment: Thank you Apple for this obscure bug.  Thank you Jim for finding a fix for this.

Comment: thanks for this saved me a ton. A quick search revealed is not a new bug. Apple should at the very minimum not allow devices to be plugged in or do the right thing FIX IT.

Answer (score 6):

When you archive your app in Xcode, you are probably not building it for all the architectures needed (armv7 for iPhone 5C). Try changing the build setting for **Build Active Architectures Only** as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17327694/70350).

Answer (score 2):

Put the Build Active Architectures Only setting to NO for both project and builds