# My app doesn't support iPhone 4s & 5 on the App Store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, architecture, app-store, app-store-connect

I have just updated a new version of my app and its not supporting iPhone 4s & 5.

From the App Store:

> **Compatibility:** Requires iOS 8.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6s, iPhone 6s Plus, iPad Air, iPad
>   Air Wi-Fi + Cellular, iPad mini 2, iPad mini 2 Wi-Fi + Cellular, iPad
>   Air 2, iPad Air 2 Wi-Fi + Cellular, iPad mini 3, iPad mini 3 Wi-Fi +
>   Cellular, iPad mini 4, iPad mini 4 Wi-Fi + Cellular, iPad Pro, iPad
>   Pro Wi-Fi + Cellular, and iPod touch (6th generation).

My older version did support all iPhone, iPad and iPod touch.

In Build settings the valid architectures are (for both debug and release): `arm64`, `armv7` and `armv7s`

Under required device capabilities I had `armv7`. My simulators show iPhone 4 & 5 and it runs great.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Iphone 4 doesn't support iOS8, but iOS8 can be installed on 4s and 5. Check info.plist in required capabilities as David Wrote. Also iPad2 is missing.

Comment: @Andrea I did. Under required device capabilities I have armv7. What's missing?

Comment: armv7 should be ok for iPhone 4s http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/05/02/how-to-indicate-what-devices-are-supported-by-your-ios-app

Comment: Yes I know that. Thank you. The reason I am asking is I had armv7 but my app can't installed on iPhone 4s and iPhone 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the answer to my question.

When I archived my app I had to select "iOS Device" and not archiving for a device that's plugged in at the time.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24149087/2053537

Answer (score 1):

Check your info.plist file for items listed under "require device capabilities" It's possible that something has crept into this array that requires iPhone 5S+ to run.

Comment: Under required device capabilities I have `armv7`. Where else can I look? My simulators show iPhone 4 & 5 and it runs great.

Answer (score 1):

Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture Only (Release) = No