# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7, ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode

I am implementing google cloud messaging in my project, and i have setup cocoapods in my project. But when I run the project it generate error, this error is 
**Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGGLCore.a(GMRProductsRequest.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGGLCore.a(GMRInAppPurchaseTransactionReporter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**. I am using Xcode 7 and swift 2 and my pod version is 1.0.0.beta.2

Please help me, I am not able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Read this post... [After update to Xcode 5 - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 or armv7s linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311075/after-update-to-xcode-5-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-armv7-or-armv)

Basically you need to remove **Build Active Architecture Only** from all your static libraries' project build settings. Xcode added this with their update as it makes Xcode compile faster since it only requires Xcode to compile for the connected device, but it is causing problems in your case so you may remove it

Answer (score 0):

I have add GameKit.framework and StoreKit.framework into Target>>General>>Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

clean project and build project.An error is solved